# Who issued the passports for travel to Russian America?

Tags: russia, law, colonial-america, travel, employment

Employees of the Russian-American Company were supposed to have seven-year passports to travel from Russia to the Company's colonies. Officials endeavored to stay in compliance, though it's clear that there wasn't always a valid passport for every employee (*Correspondence of the Governors*, pp. 71). A census form asks "by whom and where the passport was issued" (pp. 14). The Company's Main Office in St. Petersburg was one of the entities that undertook passport issuance and renewals. Closer to Company fur operations, the port commandant of Okhotsk once demanded to be sent those employees whose passports had expired (pp. 71) (a clue for [another question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/42662/commandant-of-okhotsk-and-russian-american-company)). It must be no coincidence that the Company's normal employee contract also lasted seven years and was often signed in Okhotsk. However, Miller in *Kodiak Kreol* wrote that seven-year passports were issued in Irkutsk.

Which officials could create passports for the colonies? Could one be written in Okhotsk or Petropavlovsk?

Comment: ["The Watchful Eye of the Empire: Passports and Passport Control in Russian America"](http://connection.ebscohost.com/c/articles/34238878/watchful-eye-empire-passports-passport-control-russian-america) looks relevant, but I don't have library access.